# modify scale in existing ggplot object without replacing the scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have a ggplot object. It has an x-axis label that was created by `scales_x_continuous()`. Without recreating the plot, and without changing any of the other arguments that were passed to `scale_x_continuous()`, I want to change the x-axis label. How may I do this?

There are many SO posts about updating ggplot objects after they have been created. But as best I can tell, the solutions in those posts don't apply to this particular situation. To fix ideas, here is a small example:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "oldLabel", limits = c(15, 30))
```

I want to change the x-axis label from "oldLabel" to "newLabel" without overriding the `limits` argument. Many seemingly obvious strategies mentioned in other posts don't work in this case:

1. `p + scale_x_continuous(name = "newLabel")` changes the label -- but it also changes the limits. I could get around that problem by calling `p + scale_x_continuous(name = "newLabel, limits = c(15, 30)")`. But in practice, the ggplot objects that I use may be created with many arguments to `scale_x_continuous()`, and I don't want to repeat them all just to override the x-axis label.
2. `p + xlab("newLabel")` doesn't replace the label. That is, `xlab()` seems to have no effect in this case. It would work if the original label had been specified with `xlab()`, but that isn't the case here.
3. `update_labels(p, list(x = "new x label"))` also doesn't replace the label.
4. `ggplot_build()` also seems to have no effect, at least as I've been using it:

```
library(gridExtra)
tmp <- ggplot_build(p)
tmp$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x$name     <- "newLabel"
tmp$layout$panel_params[[1]]$x.sec$name <- "newLabel"
grid.arrange(ggplot_gtable(tmp))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update the `name` parameter of the x scale object within the plot itself (not the copy that resides in the `layout` of a ggplot built object).

Here's a full reprex:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name = "oldLabel", limits = c(15, 30))

p
#> Warning: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

```r
p$scales$scales[[1]]$name <- "newLabel"

p
#> Warning: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you -- that works nicely.  /  In the example given, p$scales$scales[[1]]$name is part of the initial plot. Your solution is to overwrite it. But there are plots for which p$scales$scales[[1]]$name isn't created. (A common feature of these plots is that `scale_x_continuous()` is called after a `geom_` command. In such plots,  p$scales$scales[[1]] contains little but `super()`.) Your solution still works for these plots, but in this case, it adds a new `name` variable deep inside the plot.  /  Do you know why p$scales$scales[[1]]$name is created in some plots but not in others?

Comment: @user697473 I haven't tested this, but is it perhaps only created if a `name` parameter is passed in the `scale_x_continuous` call?

Comment: Thank you -- but that doesn't seem to be it. I've been able to generate plots for which there is no value of p$scales$scales[[1]]$name, even when the plots are created with `scale_x_continuous(name = "myLabel")`. These plots have nothing inside `p$scales$scales[[1]]` except a `range` element and `super()`, which is some sort of ggproto method.  /  By the way, something that I said in my previous comment is misleading: I've since found that `name` can be absent regardless of whether `scale_x_continuous() is called before or after a `geom_` command. I'll try to create a reproducible example.